# Spring Security LDAP Authentication should authenticate only one user

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security-ldap

I want my rest api to be restricted only for a particular user (SuperUser).
I am using Spring security the below code works fine if I give SuperUser/Password ,  it only checks for the correctness of the password.
Even if I give some random username with correct password it says authentication successful.
How to validate whether the user name given as part of BasicAuth is same as "SuperUser"

```
public class BasicAuthSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { 
    
    @Value("${users-ldap.url}")
    private String ldapUrl;

    @Value("${users-ldap.username}")
    private String userDn;

    @Value("${users-ldap.password}")
    private String password;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        
        authenticationManagerBuilder.ldapAuthentication()
        .userDnPatterns("uid={0}")
        .contextSource().url(ldapUrl)
        .managerDn(userDn)
        .managerPassword(getDrawPassword(password)).and()
        .userSearchFilter("sAMAccountName=SuperUser");
        
    }

    @RequestMapping
    public Authentication getAuth() {
        
        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        
        httpSecurity.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .antMatcher("/ws")
                .httpBasic().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

Comment: You only retrieve the user from LDAP basically ignoring the `username`. You could extend the basic auth filter to check the name before doing the authentication check.

Answer (score 0):

As per M .Denum suggestion using Custom Authentication provide I could solve the issue

` @Configuration
public class LdapAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

```
@Value("${ldap.url}")
private String ldapUrl;

@Value("${ldap.username}")
private String userDn;

@Value("${ldap.password}")
private String password;

private LdapContextSource contextSource;

private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

private void initContext() {
    contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
    contextSource.setUrl(ldapUrl);
    contextSource.setUserDn(userDn);
    contextSource.setPassword(password);
    contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
    ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
}

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    initContext();
    Filter filter = new EqualsFilter("sAMAccountName", authentication.getName());
    Boolean authenticate = ldapTemplate.authenticate(LdapUtils.emptyLdapName(), filter.encode(),
            authentication.getCredentials().toString());
    if (authenticate && (authentication.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.SERVICE_ACCOUNT)
            || authentication.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_D))) {
        UserDetails userDetails = new User(authentication.getName(), authentication.getCredentials().toString(),
                new ArrayList<>());
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
                authentication.getCredentials().toString(), new ArrayList<>());
        return auth;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
```

} `